# How to access to views of another Controller in ASP MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a view Index which is **generated automatically using Entity Framework** (with others view create,edit,delete...in one folder).

The folder name of those views is 'ProfileGa' and the controller which populate its is 'ProfileGaController' and the model is 'FlowViewModel'.

My problem is I want to access to views of anothers controllers from the view Index of 'ProfileGaController'.

***TO EXPLAIN MORE :***
[image: explication]

So, How can I access to the views of Gamme from the view of Profile_Ga (precisly Index) with an action link.

I will put the code of Index :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Helpers" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Gestion de flux de production</h2>



<p>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Ajouter une nouvelle gamme", "Create") %>
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ID Gamme
        </th>
        <th>
            Entrée
        </th>
        <th>
           Sortie
        </th>
        <th>
            Gamme Suivante
        </th>
        <th>
            Etat
        </th>
        <th>Opérations</th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model.Profile_GaItems) { %>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Gamme) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.In_Ga) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Out_Ga) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Next_Gamme) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Etat) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new { id=item.ID_Gamme }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Détails", "Details", new { id=item.ID_Gamme }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Supprimer", "Delete", new { id=item.ID_Gamme }) %>
        </td>
    </tr>


<% } %>

</table>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ProfileGa"))
   { %>
  <div><%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProfile_Ga, new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"))%> <input type="button" value="Configurer" id="btnShowGestion" /></div> 




<div id="divGestion"><%: Html.Partial("Gestion", Model) %></div>
       <% } %>   
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {





                $('#btnShowGestion').click(function () { $('#divGestion').slideToggle("slow") });



            });

</script>
<fieldset>
<legend>Gestion des Gammes</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ID Gamme
        </th>
        <th>
            ID Poste
        </th>
        <th>
           Nombre de Passage
        </th>
        <th>
            Position
        </th>
        <th>
            Poste Précédent
        </th>
         <th>
            Poste Suivant
        </th>
        <th>Opérations</th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model.GaItems) { %>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Gamme) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Poste) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nbr_Passage) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_Posts) %>
        </td>
         <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Next_Posts) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink(?????????????????) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink(?????????????????) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink(?????????????????) %>
        </td>
    </tr>


<% } %>
</table>
 </fieldset>     
</asp:Content>
```

***Note :***
The '????????' in the ***ActionLink*** this is where I want to access to the views of Gamme.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the signatures of the `ActionLink` extension method ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues)
```

The 3rd parameter `controllerName` is what you want here.

Thus, in your case:

```
Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", "Gamme" new { id=item.ID_Gamme })
```

You're also mentioning that you '**want to access the views**' of another Controller, that's not exactly what the `ActionLink` method is about, this method would simply issue an `a` tag (link) with the appropriate Url that will load the requested [Controller.Action].

Comment: thx but the link takes me of the Edit of Profile_Ga, that's means no diffrence between this : Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", "Gamme" new { id=item.ID_Gamme }) and this :  <%: Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new { id=item.ID_Gamme }) %>

Comment: i saw your edit,,,so i have to not use ActionLink to access to another controller,,so what is the solution ?

Comment: sorry,,,I want that take me to the view 'Edit' in the Folder 'Gamme' of the controller 'GammeController'

Comment: Maybe i get you wrong. but, In MVC, `Views` are not meant to be accessed directly, only using `Actions`. please read the last paragraph in my answer or read more on how the MVC Framework works.

Comment: yes I read,,,i am just now need an approach how i put a link to take to the view of Edit of the Controller 'Gamme',,Is that Possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that from the controller if you prefer, rather than a URL

using this line of code in the action method

`return View("ViewName", model)`

Comment: Then the first one will be your answer :)

Comment: I created a new view to that controller ,,,but I have some problems of null values,,,Hang On plz,,,I will give you link to the new question

Comment: take a look plz : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649178/null-object-refrence-in-the-acess-of-the-view-in-asp-mvc-and-ef