# Null Object refrence in the acess of the view in ASP MVC and EF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a view Index which contains some links to othres views.

Among those views, there is 'Update.aspx' which i created (not generated automaticalu by Entity Framework).

Its object is to edit some values in a table 'Gamme' in my base.

The problem is that : when I click on the link of this view (Update), this error appears :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This a part of the code of the view Index which contain the link for the view Upadate :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Helpers" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


<fieldset>
<legend>Gestion des Gammes</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ID Gamme
        </th>
        <th>
            ID Poste
        </th>
        <th>
           Nombre de Passage
        </th>
        <th>
            Position
        </th>
        <th>
            Poste Précédent
        </th>
         <th>
            Poste Suivant
        </th>
        <th>Opérations</th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model.GaItems) { %>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Gamme) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Poste) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nbr_Passage) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_Posts) %>
        </td>
         <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Next_Posts) %>
        </td>
        <td>

            <%: Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Update", new { id=item.ID_Gamme }) %> 

        </td>
    </tr>


<% } %>

</table>
 </fieldset>     
</asp:Content>
```

and this a part of the code of the controller ProfileGa :

```
public ActionResult Update(string id)
        {
            FlowViewModel flv = db.FlowViewModels.Find(id);
            return View(flv);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(FlowViewModel model)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + model.Nbr_Passage);

                Gamme G = new Gamme();
                ListG.Remove(G);
                db.Gammes.Remove(G); 
                G.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
                G.ID_Poste = model.SelectedPoste;
                G.Last_Posts = model.PostePrecedentSelected;
                G.Next_Posts = model.PosteSuivantSelected;
                G.Nbr_Passage = int.Parse(model.Nbr_Passage);
                G.Position = int.Parse(model.Position);
                ListG.Add(G);
                db.Gammes.Add(G);
                db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

and this is the code of the model FlowViewModel :

```
public class FlowViewModel
    {

        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList PostesItems { get; set; }
        public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
     public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }



        public string SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }


      public string SelectedPoste { get; set; }

      public string PostePrecedentSelected { get; set; } 
      public string PosteSuivantSelected { get; set; }


        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string  Nbr_Passage { get; set; }

        public List<Gamme> ListG = new List<Gamme>();

    }
```

and finaly the code of the View 'UPDATE' :

```
asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Update
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Modifier une gamme</h2>

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Gamme</legend>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProfile_Ga, new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"))%></div>

         <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPoste, Model.PostesItems)%></div>


         <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Nbr_Passage)%></div><div class="editor-field"> <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nbr_Passage)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Position)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Précédent :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PostePrecedentSelected, Model.PostesItems)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems)%></div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Reour à la liste", "Index") %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

On the following line of code in your controller you seem to be fetching the model from somewhere:

```
FlowViewModel flv = db.FlowViewModels.Find(id);
```

Make sure (by placing a breakpoint here) that all properties that you are using in your Update view are properly initialized here. Possible causes for this exception are that either the `flv` is null or some of its properties that are being used.

Usually when you get a NullReferenceException at runtime, the YSOD is pointing to the exact location of your view in which you are getting this exception. This will give you a hint at which property you need to populate.

Comment: yes,,,when i put a breakpoint there and check,,i find the values of flv is NULL

Comment: Then this is your problem. The `db.FlowViewModels.Find(id);` method returns null. You will have to fix it. If you pass `null` as a model to a view you should not be attempting to use any of the model properties without checking whether the model is not null first.

Comment: thx,,I understand ,,,but how I will fix it ? I think that my code is correct,,,It s works with others models

Comment: You haven't shown the code of this method and expect us telling you how to fix it? Maybe there's no record with the specified `id` in your database or whatever you are using. Debug your code and see where it returns null inside this method.

Comment: I am sorry ! The code of this methode is predefined (I didn't write it). It is a methode of DbSet,,this is its definition : public TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues);